# How to write a jQuery function with a callback that you can pass Params to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function loadProjects(pID) {

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) {###Run any supplied call back here####}
    });
}
```

I call this function like so loadProjects(1);

Issue is I want to be able to define a callBack function after success, and I'd like to include it when I do loadProjects(1, pong(12)). I want to be able to supply params to the callback.

How can I have a function accept a callback?
How can I pass a callback to that function?

Something like

```
function loadProjects(pID, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) {###Run any supplied call back here####}
    });
}
```

Where I could then call:

```
loadProjects(22, pong(12))
```

Problem is when I try this, pong(12) is running immediately, and not later when called in the loadProjects function?

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
function loadProjects(pID, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) {
           if ($.isFunction(callback))
              callback();
        }
    });

}

loadProjects(1, function() { pong(12); });
```

or:

```
function loadProjects(pID, callback, value) {

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) {
           if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
              if (value) {
                 callback(value);
              }else{
                 callback();
              }
           }

        }
    });

}

loadProjects(1, pong, 12);
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you. I will accept once SO lets me. 5 more mins, grrr

Comment: +1 for `$.isFunction`, which is prettier than `typeof foo == 'function'`

Comment: @karim79 Which also fails in WebKit... `typeof /regex/ === 'function'` :P (if not using jQuery, I use `callback instanceof Function`).

Comment: @ColdTree look at this link if you need to do something more complex:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @alex - +1 for the webkit thing, I did not know about it.

Comment: @karim79 Either did I until recently, and now I'm spreading the good word :)

Answer (score 2):

```
loadProjects(22, function(){pong(12);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var loadProjects = (function(pID, callback) {
    var params = { "property" : "value" }
    $.ajax({
       url: myURL,
       success: function (dataJS) { callback(params); }
    });
})

loadProjects(22, function(p){ console.log(p); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadProjects(pID, callback) {
    var callbackArgs = arguments;
    callbackArgs.shift();
    callbackArgs.shift();

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        success: function (dataJS) {
            // Null or this can be used depending on desired behavaiour
            // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply
            callback.apply(null, callbackArgs);
        }
   });
}
```

Example usage:

```
loadProjects(22, pong, 12);
loadProjects(22, pong, 12, 'foo', 'bar');
```

12, foo, and bar are all passed to the pong callback.